# Store IP range instead of normal IP

Tags: php, pdo

Right now my script basically reads visitor's IP and writes it down to the database.

For example `getIP()` returns visitors IP address, on some illegal action his IP is getting inserted to the database 'black_list'. Now, on site visit script checks if user's IP in `black_list` table, if it's in the table and `date_added` less than 30 min ago, script doesn't lat the visitor visit the website.

Now since there might be many blocked IPs I want to make `getIP()` return IP range instead of whole IP address.

Comment: each and every particular request comes form one and just one IP address. What "range" are you looking for?

Comment: Carrier-grade NAT is very prevalent these days, in particular with mobile networks. When are website developers going to stop working under the fallacy that remote IP address is a good way to identify a single remote user? Even before you mentioned IP ranges, your solution is likely to result in large numbers of users being continually blocked for no reason.

Comment: @OlegDubas the number that goes after last dot ( something like 127.0.0.* instead of 127.0.0.1 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
$ip = '127.0.0.1'; // or $ip = getIP(), whatever
$ip = explode('.', $ip);
$ip[3] = '*';
$ip_range = implode('.', $ip);
```

Which will give you `'127.0.0.*'`